# AngularFire2 Suscribe return values FAIL

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, observable

I have this code in my authService

```
    constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.authState = afAuth.authState;
    this.authState.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
        this.authState = user;
    });
    if ( this.authenticated ) {
      // this.router.navigate([`/content`]);
    }
  }

  // Returns true if user is logged in
  get authenticated(): any {
    return this.authState;
  }
```

I call the `get authenticated` and it returns undefined:

COMPONENT

```
    constructor(
    private auth: AuthService
  ) {
      this.currentUser = this.auth.authenticated;
  }
showUser() {
    console.log(this.currentUser.uid);
  }
```

I need help to fix it, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Whats your purpose? What do you need and why?

I still don't know why you need it like this. But i think it's a problem of the lifecycle hook ([you can find here the doc](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)).

try it like this. this is your component

```
export class *YOUR_COMPONENT* implements OnInit {

   private authenticatedUser$: Subscription; <= import rxjs/Subscription
   private authenticatedUser: User; <= import firebase/app

   constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
     this.authenticatedUser$ = this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser().subscribe((user: User) => {
      // Here you're saving the firebase.user in your var authenticatedUser
      this.authenticatedUser = user;
   });

   ngOnInit() {
      // Check if user is logged in..
      if(this.authenticatedUser) {
        // When true, your code here..
      }
   }

   ....}
```

and here your authService:

```
   export class authService {

     constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { <= import angularfire2/auth/auth
       // constructor is empty
     });

     getAuthenticatedUser() {
       return this.auth.authState;
     }

   ....}
```

this should work..

Comment: Thank you, I need check if the user is logged or not. How do you do this?

Comment: and my code is a service, i put this code into constructor of the authService. I can't add ngOnInit() in a service

Comment: Have a look at the code above the comments, i updated the code. And don't forget to unsubscribe the Subscription somewhere!! Above my code you will see the answer of DrNio, the explanation I forgot to write.

Comment: I don't know why, but this line don't works`this.authState = user;` into the subscribe all works fine but outside that line dont saved the data

Answer (score 0):

What happens is normal. `console.log` is synchronous call. what is inside the subscription is asynchronous. so even if the `console.log` is written after the .subcribe and can be executed faster indeed. That is why `console.log( this.authState.uid );` prints `undefined`.

Also, I would avoid adding any logic in the `contructor`.

Better having the .subscribe `OnInit()` and try to access the `this. authState` on `AfterViewInit()` lifecycle.

Final note, you can even save the subscription that you will have `OnInit` and `.unsubscribe` `OnDestroy` :)

Answer (score 0):

`AngularFireAuth.authState` is async and an `Observable`. [You can read up on what an Observable is here on the ReativeX site](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html).

In sort, the authState observable is a sequence of values over time, aysnc (takes some time to resolve), and lazy (you need to subscribe to get a value, which is why your console.log outside is not working.)

If you need to access the "current" value outside of a subscribe block I recommend using a `BehaviorSubject` ([again check out ReactiveX for more information on subjects](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)):

```
currentAuthState: BehaviorSubject<firebase.User|null|undefined>;

constructor(afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  this.currentAuthState = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
  afAuth.authState.subscribe(this.currentAuthState);
}
```

Then you can access: `this.currentAuthState.getValue()` to see what the current value is; `.subscribe` to listen to changes; use any other RxJS operator such as map, do, swtichMap, etc.; and use an async pipes in your view `{{ (currentAuthState | async)?.email }}`

It will be `undefined` when loading, `null` if no user is logged in, and a `firebase.User` if a user is logged in.